# Run Perl Script From Unix Shell Script

Tags: perl, shell, unix

Hi I have a Unix Shell Script call Food.sh ; I have a Perl Script call Track.pl. Is there a way where I can put Track.pl's code in to Food.sh code and still have it work ? Track.pl requires one arugement to label a name of a folder.

Basically it will run like this.

```
Unix Shell Script codes RUN

step into 

Perl Script codes RUN
Put in name of folder for Perl script
Rest of script runs

exit out.
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have a few options.

1. You can pass the code to Perl using `-e`/`-E`.

   ```
    ...
    perl -e'

       print "Hello, World!\n";

    '
    ...
   ```

   Con: Escaping can be a pain.<sup>[1]</sup>
2. You can pass the code via STDIN.

   ```
    ...
    perl <<'END_OF_PERL'

       print "Hello, World!\n";

    END_OF_PERL
    ...
   ```

   Con: The script can't use STDIN.
3. You can create a virtual file.

   ```
    ...
    perl <(
    cat <<'END_OF_PERL'

       print "Hello, World!\n";

    END_OF_PERL
    )
    ...
   ```

   Con: Wordy.
4. You can take advantage of `perl`'s `-x` option.

   ```
    ...
    perl -x -- "$0"
    ...
    exit

    #!perl
    print "Hello, World!\n";
   ```

   Con: Can only have one snippet.

   `$0` is the path to the shell script being executed. It's passed to `perl` as the program to run. The `-x` tells Perl to start executing at the `#!perl` line rather than the first line.

Ref: [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)

---

1. Instances of `'` in the program needs to escaped using `'\''`.

   You could also rewrite the program to avoid using `'`. For example, you could use double-quoted string literals instead of single-quoted string literals. Or replace the delimiter of single-quoted string literals (e.g. `q{...}` instead of `'...'`). As for single-quoted inside of double-quoted and regex literals, these can be replaced with `\x27`, which you might find nicer than `'\''`.

Comment: From the linked document: *`-x` tells Perl that the program is embedded in a larger chunk of unrelated text, such as in a mail message. Leading garbage will be discarded until the first line that starts with #! and contains the string "perl". Any meaningful switches on that line will be applied.*

Comment: When I came back from reading `perlrun` in preparation for answering, I found two perfectly good answers waiting.  You folks are just too fast...

Comment: Thanks, I thought it might be useful to include that information here to keep your answer self-contained. So the `exit` belongs to the shell script and the `"$0"` is an argument passed to the the perl script.

Comment: @TomFenech `$0` is the shell script's own file name.  It's passed to perl itself as the program to run.  The `-x` limits that running to stuff after a line starting with "#!" and containing "perl"

Answer (score 1):

(I'm assuming your goal is just to have all of the code in a single file so that you don't have multiple files to install)

Sure, there's a way to do this, but it's cumbersome.  You might want to consider converting the shell script entirely to Perl (or the Perl script entirely to shell).

So ... **A** way to do this might be:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "shell"

perl -E '
say "perl with arg=$ARGV[0]"
' fred

echo "shell again"
```

Of course, you'd have to be careful with your quotes within the Perl part of the program.

You might also be able to use a heredoc for the Perl part to avoid quoting issues, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: I think that should be `-e`, not `-E`.

Comment: @Tom Fenech, `-E` is `-e` plus an implied `use feature ":".substr($^V,1);`.

Comment: So it enables the [feature bundle](http://perldoc.perl.org/feature.html) for the version of Perl running the one-liner.

Comment: @TomFenech Yep. It was introduced in 5.10.0 so you won't find it in older versions of perl.