# How to embed and run a multi-line perl script stored in a bash variable in a bash script (without immediately running perl)

Tags: bash, shell, perl, embed

How do I replace `[RUN_ABOVE_PERL_SORTING_SCRIPT_HERE]` with something that runs [this perl script](https://github.com/philips/acl/blob/master/test/sort-getfacl-output) stored in a bash variable?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# The perl script to sort getfacl output:
# https://github.com/philips/acl/blob/master/test/sort-getfacl-output

find /etc -name .git -prune -o -print | xargs getfacl -peL | [RUN_ABOVE_PERL_SORTING_SCRIPT_HERE] > /etc/.facl.nogit.txt
```

Notes:

1. I do not want to employ 2 files (a bash script and a perl script) to solve this problem; I want the functionality to be stored all in one bash script file.
2. I do not want to immediately run the perl script when storing the perl-script variable, because I want to run it later in the [getfacl(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/getfacl) bash pipeline shown below.
3. There's many similar stackoverflow questions+answers, but none that I can find (that has clean-reading code, anyway?) that solve both the a) multi-line and b) delayed-execution (or the embedded perl script) portion of this problem.
4. And to clarify: this problem is not specifically about getfacl(1), which is simply an catalyst to explore how to embed perl scripts--and possibly other scripting languages like python--into bash variables for delayed execution in a bash script.)

Answer (score 2):

Employ the [bash read command](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html), which reads the perl script into a variable that's executed later in the bash script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# sort getfacl output: the following code is copied from:
# https://github.com/philips/acl/blob/master/test/sort-getfacl-output

read -r -d '' SCRIPT <<'EOS'
#!/usr/bin/env perl -w

undef $/;
print join("\n\n", sort split(/\n\n/, <>)), "\n\n";
EOS

find /etc -name .git -prune -o -print | xargs getfacl -peL | perl -e "$SCRIPT" > /etc/.facl.nogit.txt
```

Comment: Since your script doesn't contain any single quotes, you could also just assign it to `SCRIPT` as a single quoted string that contains linebreaks.

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminW. I'll also want to support future scripts that may contain single quotes or have other needs for multi-(hard?)-lined scripts.

Answer (score 1):

This is covered by [*Run Perl Script From Unix Shell Script*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25167436/589924).

As they apply here:

1. You can pass the code to Perl using `-e`/`-E`.

   ```
   perl -e"$script"
   ```

   or

   ```
   perl -e"$( curl "$url" )"
   ```
2. You can pass the code via STDIN.

   ```
   printf %s "$script" | perl -e"$script"
   ```

   or

   ```
   curl "$url" | perl
   ```

   (This won't work for you because you need STDIN.)
3. You can create a virtual file.

   ```
   perl <( printf %s "$script" )
   ```

   or

   ```
   perl <( curl "$url" )
   ```
4. You can take advantage of `perl`'s `-x` option.

   (Not applicable if you want to download the script dynamically.)

---

All of the above assume the following command has already been executed:

```
url='https://github.com/philips/acl/blob/master/test/sort-getfacl-output'
```

Some of the above assume the following command has already been executed:

```
script="$( curl "$url" )
```